# using ajax and jquery for search and grabbing url parameters

Tags: jquery, ajax, url, search, get

I'm having problems trying to figure this out. It may be simple but it seems like its that time of day where my brain is fried... I'm trying to create an input field (search engine to my mysql database) and I want to be able to use ajax to send the parameters and then on success go to the page with the parameters in URL, so users can bookmark, and go back whenever they need to.

I'm not sure if that's the best way to do so. But I don't want to write all my sql query in the same page and would like to have a separate page searching through my database.

So far I have this code:

```
$('.search').click(function(){
        var d = $('input').val();
        mainSearch = 'd=' + d;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "ajax/mysql_search.php",
            data: mainSearch,
            success: function(data)
                {
                var url = "index.php?d="+d;
                window.location = url;
                }
        });         

    });
```

The search would typically be in the index.php, and I want to keep this name there. If I do the traditional `<form action='index.php?d=<?php ...code... ?>'></form>` I know I can achieve, what I'm trying to do. But that means I have to write all my code in index.php. And I want to keep this url, so if users search it'll be like index.php?d=...(parameters).

Comment: If you arent displaying the results dynamic, what would be the point in doing it with Ajax then? You need to have the MYSQL function on the index.php anyway, for displaying the results?

Comment: i am displaying my results dynamically. I'm trying get it so I don't have to write my mysql functions in index.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.search').click(function(){
    var d = $('input').val();
    mainSearch = 'd=' + d;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "ajax/mysql_search.php",
        data: mainSearch,
        success: function(data)
            {
                var url = "index.php?d="+d;
                $.get(url, function(data) { // my mistake updated the code
                    $('.result').html(data); //<----------------------div where you want to load that page.Also you need to design your HTML structure based on .result div
                });
            }
    });         
});
```

Comment: I don't get the $.get(...) part? in ajax/mysql_search.php should already have those parameters that I'm trying to get from mainSearch

Comment: I am really sorry for the mistake. It should be url instead

Comment: this doesn't work? again, I'm trying to not just show the result without refreshing, but I'm trying to show the result with the search paramaters in the URL